# Switching back and forth between frames in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program that requires you to switch screens. However, when I run the code I can switch to the second screen but am met with an empty window and error message when trying to switch back to the first.

Is there any way to fix this issue without the use of classes? The method I used and the error message is below

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()  # creates a window

f1 = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background="red")
f2 = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=200, background= 'blue')

def SwitchToSetup(prev, next_frame): #Destroys the previous screen and creates the setup screen
    prev.destroy()
    next_frame()

def Screen1():

    def NextScreen():
      SwitchToSetup(f1, Screen2)

    f1.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)

    greeting = tk.Button(f1, text="Screen1", font=("comic sans", 60), command = NextScreen)  # creates a lable with text
    greeting.pack()

    window.mainloop()

def Screen2():

    def NextScreen():
      SwitchToSetup(f2, Screen1)

    f2.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)

    greeting = tk.Button(f2, text="Screen2", font=("comic sans", 60), command = NextScreen)  # creates a lable with text
    greeting.pack()

    window.mainloop()

Screen1()
```

This is the error that comes when running the code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alysw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\alysw\OneDrive - St Anne's Catholic School\NEA stuff\Computing\attempts\switch screens practice.py", line 27, in NextScreen
    SwitchToSetup(f2, Screen1)
  File "C:\Users\alysw\OneDrive - St Anne's Catholic School\NEA stuff\Computing\attempts\switch screens practice.py", line 10, in SwitchToSetup
    next_frame()
  File "C:\Users\alysw\OneDrive - St Anne's Catholic School\NEA stuff\Computing\attempts\switch screens practice.py", line 17, in Screen1
    f1.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
  File "C:\Users\alysw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2396, in pack_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame"
```

Comment: After calling `prev.destroy()`, you cannot reuse the old Frame when you want to switch back to it.  Try `prev.pack_forget()` instead, which merely hides it.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the problem or not, but you shouldn't be calling `window.mainloop()` more than once for the life of  your program.

Comment: @jasonharper the solution works but causes another frame to appear below the previous when switching back to the first frame. I have found changing .pack() to .place() solved this issue